# VBA userform now showing in quick access toolbar in excel 2016

Tags: vba, userform, excel-2016

I have a userform which I cannot select in the quick access toolbar to add to the ribbon.

All of the other macros I have are visible and can be selected to be added to the quick access toolbar.

I have the name of the userform and command buttons in the userform code matching the name listed within their reposective properties windows.

I have been able to add userforms to previous versions of excel so I am not sure if anything has changed for excel 2016.

```
Sub userform1_show()

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Load.Linux_unix_scan_tab_only
    Linux_unix_scan_tab_only.Linux_unix_scan_tab_only
    End

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Load.unix_SSHkey_tabs
    unix_SSHkey_tabs.Linux_unix_scan_and_SSH_Key_trust_tabs

End Sub

Private Sub userform_click()

End Sub
```

Comment: are you calling UserForm1.Show from within the form module?

Comment: I want to add userform1 to the quick access toolbar in excel, then using the userform the two subs CommandButton1_Click and CommandButton2_Click will run. I think I am calling the UserForm1.Show from within the form module yes.

Comment: put the sub with UserForm1.Show into a standard module and it should work.